# python get subprocess commandline result

Tags: python, subprocess

```
print(str(subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/hello/automan.git'])))
```

It returns something .. `"returned non-zero exit status 128"`

What I want is like..:

```
Cloning into 'automan'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 51, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
remote: Total 51 (delta 17), reused 45 (delta 11), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (51/51), done.
```

How to get subprocess result like above?

Comment: Why do you use `check_call()`?

Comment: Your code would produce that output if git was functioning properly.

Comment: also, your `print()` doesn't really do anything because check_call returns None. output from subprocess will go to stdout without the print (as long as you don't redirect it)

Comment: The git repo https://github.com/hello/automan does not seem to exist as a public repo. Either you have a typo in the URL, or you are failing to provide some credentials to access a private repo. Either way, it doesn't look like a problem with subprocess.

Comment: @OlvinRoght There is no other reason, If you have better way to do this, I'll use that.

Comment: @jordanm Actually I use this code on AWS lambda, so that I can't see stdout on lambda. That's why I use this code.

Comment: @alaniwi Yes actually, github.com/hello/automan is fake url, but It's just example.